# React Native How to get messages in background from firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

- I don't know how to receive data in background like other message apps.
- when app is in background I want to count to unread messages.

At now run my app and enter any chat room and I leave the chat room and then I can see unread count badge

I just want to see badge without them.

My English is very bad. I'd appreciate your help.

My code is here

```
  const [unReadMessageCountToBadge] = useCollection(
    db
      .collection('chats')
      .doc(id)
      .collection('messages')
      .where('user', '==', recipientEmail)
      .where('unread', '==', true),
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    unReadMessageCountToBadge?.docs.map(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data().user);
      if (doc.data().user !== user) {
        badgeStateDispatch({type: BADGE_COUNT});
      }
    });
  }, [unReadMessageCountToBadge]);
```

Answer (score -2):

React Native doesn't support firebase